# Flexbox container centering challenge

Tags: css, flexbox, center

Good morning,

I am having a challenge with centering a flexbox container itself. I have managed to center all 5 elements within the flexbox but cannot actually get the container itself to center horizontally into the middle of the page.

I have watched a tutorial after getting stuck on this and can see my code is the same except for the naming of containers. Timestamp provided for the exact second where you can see their code: https://youtu.be/fJc18fT4T3s?t=542. In their tutorial, the "trend-container" which is my "image-container" is centered whereas mine is not. I have tried using margin: 0 auto; but this does nothing and the container stays on the left side of the page.

I have had to add text-align: center to mine as the text was not aligning.

If anyone can advise what I have done wrong to not allow this flexbox container to center that would be great as I am a bit stumped!

```css
body {
  font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: black;
}

.mission h2,
#featured h2 {
  margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mission h4,
#featured h4 {
  margin: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ---------------Navigation ----------------*/

.navbar {
  height: 69px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px seashell solid;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0.45rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.navlist {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0.45rem;
}

.navlist a {
  color: seashell;
}

.navbar .navlist ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar .navlist ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}


/* ------------------Banner Section --------------*/

#mission {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg");
  margin: 70px auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mission {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/*---------------Tea of the Month ------------------*/

.image-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.image img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tea Cozy</title>
  <link href="C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Coding\Projects\teacosy\global.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <!-----------------Nav Bar--------------------->


  <nav class="navbar">
    <img class="logo" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="Tea Cozy logo">
    <div class="navlist">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#featured">Featured Tea</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-------------------Banner--------------------->


  <div id="mission">
    <div class="mission">
      <h2>Our Misson</h2>
      <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-------------------Tea of the Month-------------------->


  <div id="featured">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg">
      <h4>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg">
      <h4>Seasonal Donuts</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg">
      <h4>Myrtle Ave Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg">
      <h4>Bedford Bizarre Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `display: inline-flex` to `display: flex` and adding `margin: 0 auto` to the `<div class="image-container">` container fixes the center alignment issue for that section of the page.

```css
body {
  font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: black;
}

.mission h2,
#featured h2 {
  margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.mission h4,
#featured h4 {
  margin: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ---------------Navigation ----------------*/

.navbar {
  height: 69px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px seashell solid;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0.45rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.navlist {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0.45rem;
}

.navlist a {
  color: seashell;
}

.navbar .navlist ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar .navlist ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}


/* ------------------Banner Section --------------*/

#mission {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg");
  margin: 70px auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mission {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/*---------------Tea of the Month ------------------*/

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tea Cozy</title>
  <link href="C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Coding\Projects\teacosy\global.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <!-----------------Nav Bar--------------------->


  <nav class="navbar">
    <img class="logo" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="Tea Cozy logo">
    <div class="navlist">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#featured">Featured Tea</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-------------------Banner--------------------->


  <div id="mission">
    <div class="mission">
      <h2>Our Misson</h2>
      <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-------------------Tea of the Month-------------------->


  <div id="featured">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg">
      <h4>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg">
      <h4>Spiced Rum Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg">
      <h4>Seasonal Donuts</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg">
      <h4>Myrtle Ave Tea</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg">
      <h4>Bedford Bizarre Tea</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Jozzie Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

for "image-container" the parent that is "body" is not a flex or grid item. quick fix set: body to be a flex container and "flex-direction to column, then for "image-container" set "align-self: center;" like so:

```
body {
    font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: seashell;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
.image-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
}
```